# KDE Plasma - Plasmoid "Menu11"

Tags: kubuntu

I have installed the "Menu11", which came with a theme, but when I try to use it, there pops out the following message:

```
file:///home/jona/.local/share/plasma/plasmoids/menu11/contents/ui/main.qml:60:9: Type MenuRepresentation unavailable

file:///home/jona/.local/share/plasma/plasmoids/menu11/contents/ui/MenuRepresentation.qml:137:13: Type MainColumnItem unavailable

file:///home/jona/.local/share/plasma/plasmoids/menu11/contents/ui/MainColumnItem.qml:551:5: Type Footer unavailable

file:///home/jona/.local/share/plasma/plasmoids/menu11/contents/ui/Footer.qml:31:1: module "org.kde.plasma.private.quicklaunch" is not installed
```

Can you please just tell me how to solve those problems, because I don't know how to.
I thank you all.

Comment: Please edit your question and add details which Ubuntu release you are using.